# Golang: Passing channels through empty interfaces

Tags: go

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be trivial until I read up and now it seems like it should be really complex. ;-)
I've knocked up a test pattern to illustrate:
http://play.golang.org/p/Re88vJZvPT

At the most basic I'm trying to have a function that can read data from a channel and spit it out on another one. Easy. The test does this as long as you use the pusher function shown.
However the problem with this is that doing it this way I would need a different pusher function for each type of data I want to push through it.
Now I've done similar things in the past with an empty interface as nothing in the pusher code cares about what's in the data structure. What I can't figure out is when I'm dealing with channels of an un-cared-about data structure.

To illustrate the concept of what I'm trying to achieve please see the function pusher_naive_generic.

However that doesn't work either so more reading up implied the way to do it was making use of reflection and finally you see my pusher_reflect_generic function(obviously this won't achieve the same intended function as the others it's showing where I got to before getting stuck).
Which still fails because I can't get from an interface that contains a chan to the structure read from that chan.

Hopefully the code makes more sense of what I'm trying to achieve than my words actually do. I can make all of this work by explicitly coding for every type, but what I can't figure out how to do is code it for *any* future type.

Comment: What's exactly doesn't work with `pusher_naive_generic`? For me it worked http://play.golang.org/p/t-GrHQGlGf And I would suggest using type assertion instead of reflection

Comment: Are you trying to receive from a channel of whatever type? Any reason not to just use [`reflect.(*Value).Recv`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Recv)?

Comment: Okay I see what you've done  to make that work ;-)n_chan := make(chan TestType)
  out_chan := make(chan TestType)
becomes:
  in_chan := make(chan interface{})
  out_chan := make(chan interface{})
Which makes sense. However I was hoping for the ability to express the connections as their type as seen by the user rather than as empty channels. I had experimented with doing type assertions at the instance phase to avoid having to do that, but I couldn't make that work.
I'm just trying to mek this transparent to the user in the same way you can with other none channel types

Comment: I think OP is confused why `chan TestType` is not assertable/convertible to `chan interface{}`. Is that the problem, OP?

Comment: Yes, it's the external user interface to this I am trying to keep clean without forcing them to declare it as a channel of an empty interface

Comment: Can't figure our how to mark this as answered (First time asking a question in years of searching stack overflow)

But reflect.Recv() was what I was missing. Knew there'd be a way, there always is ;-)

Many Thanks

Comment: There's a clickable check mark beneath the score indicator on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, then this might be the solution:

http://play.golang.org/p/xiDO7xkoW4

```
func forwardChannel(i interface{}, o interface{}) {

    it, ot := reflect.TypeOf(i), reflect.TypeOf(o)

    if it != ot {
        panic("forwardChannel: both arguments must be of the same type")
    }

    iv, ov := reflect.ValueOf(i), reflect.ValueOf(o)

    for {
        v, k := iv.Recv()
        if !k {
            break
        }
        ov.Send(v)
    }

    ov.Close()

}
```

Note that `Recv`, `Send` and `Close` panic if `i` and `o` are not channels.